# How to make UIBarButtonSystemItem bordered?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have play UIBarButtonItem on UIToolbar. I want to make the style bordered. As it is system item, is there a way to make it bordered style?

```
UIBarButtonItem *systemItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:self  action:@selector(play:)];
```

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to accept the answer. Just sayin' ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `UIBarButtonItem`'s `style` property:

```
systemItem1.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
```

See the [`UIBarButtonItem` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html).